# Capture Traffic In AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pcap, packet-sniffers

I want to capture all traffic request initiated from my python function in AWS Lambda and create a pcap file for analysis.

In python function i am using headless chromium browser and opening an input URL.

Comment: the response generated by your python function and request received by your python function?

Comment: Description added.

Comment: use cloudwatch monitoring

Answer (score 0):

You could possible activate [VPC Traffic Mirroring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/what-is-traffic-mirroring.html) on the ENI used by the AWS Lambda function, but this would only be temporary because Lambda functions can add and remove ENIs over time.

> Traffic Mirroring is an Amazon VPC feature that you can use to copy network traffic from an elastic network interface of Amazon EC2 instances. You can then send the traffic to out-of-band security and monitoring appliances for Content inspection, Threat monitoring and Troubleshooting.

The mirrored traffic would be sent to an Amazon EC2 instance, where you could (somehow) capture and analyze the traffic.

Comment: Using this approach, is there any way to correlate specific packets back to a Lambda Request ID?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Traffic Mirroring only works on EC2 instance ENIs and NOT on Lambda, PrivateLink or other ENIs.